# C# Tutorial - Output PowerShell Command in C# Winform App

Tags: c#, windows, forms, powershell

As the title says I want to do a C# app and running powershell scripts and print the output in TextBox.
I followed the tutorial from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cIrCce5l7NU and everthing works as in the video but I have one problem my script never ends or it last for 10 minutes and I need to output in the TextBox in realtime with the outpout of Powershell line by line. I've tried different approaches but it seems that I cannot make it work.

Thanks!
This is the powershell script as example:

test.ps1 - prints numbers foverver

```
for (;;)
{
    $i++; Write-Host $i
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop so it never ends. You need a `foreach (PSObject pSObject in results)` to loop through a `Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();`

```cs
   private string RunScript(string script)
            {
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runspace.Open();
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(script);
            pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
            Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
            runspace.Close();
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PSObject pSObject in results)
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(pSObject.ToString());
            return string.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Hi this is the same code as in the video, and yes it can be that I have an infite loop script and I want to display it line by line. More then that the las line should be
 return stringBuilder.ToString();

Comment: Pls post a screenshot of your current output